# changing search query address

Tags: php, html, apache

I'm trying to change the search address using PHP to allow users to search a website for themselves.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHPSELF']; ?>">
    <input type="text" id="text" name="text_name" class="mytext" />

    <?php
   $text = $_POST["text_name"];
$text = urlencode($text);
?>

<input id="search" type="submit" value="" style="border-style: none; background: url('search.png') no-repeat; width: 50px; height: 50px;">
</form>

        <?php
       $url = "http://www.bestbuy.ca/Search/SearchResults.aspx?type=product&page=1&sortBy=relevance&sortDir=desc&query=" .  $text;
echo $text;
$output = file_get_contents($url);
echo $output;
//echo $url;
       ?>


    <form method="get" action="<?php> echo $url; ?>">

    </form>
```

When i run the website using an apache server and search using my search bar, a blank page loads. Any ideas on why? I'm trying to get it to search the best buy website using the query. I know best buy has an API but i want to do it this way.

Comment: Probably because Best Buy has measures to prevent external requests like this.

Comment: @RCNeil but I even tried using the walmart query and I still get a blank white screen when something is searched. Could it be that every popular website has measures to prevent external request, and if so, why?

Comment: I don't know if that is why your code is working or not.  I imagine large websites would prevent external requests like this because you could essentially bog down their system pretty quickly if you wanted to.  Why would they use their resources to help someone other than their customer?